# new List or List Pool?

Tags: c#

In C#, what is better for performance?

Assuming this is all declared in a class called "MyStaticClass"

```
     void FunctionThatGetsCalledAlot(...)
     {
        List<SomeClass> previousAttributes = new List<SomeClass>();
        previousAttributes.AddRange(SomeStuff);
        node.RemoveAttributes();
        ....
     }
```

Or this:

```
    private class ThreadSafeObjectPool<T> where T : new()
    {
        private readonly Stack<T> pool = new Stack<T>();

        public T Get()
        {
            lock (this.pool)
            {
                if (this.pool.Count > 0)
                {
                    return this.pool.Pop();
                }
            }

            return new T();
        }

        public void Return(T v)
        {
            lock (this.pool)
            {
                this.pool.Push(v);
            }
        }
    }

     private static readonly ThreadSafeObjectPool<List<SomeClass>> previousAttributes = new ObjectPool<List<SomeCLass>>();
     void FunctionThatGetsCalledAlot(...)
     {
        List<SomeClass> previousAttributes = MyStaticClass.previousAttributes.Get();

        try
        {
           previousAttributes.Clear();
           previousAttributes.AddRange(SomeStuff);
           ....
        }
        finally
        {
             MyStaticClass.previousAttributes.Return(previousAttributes);
        }
     }
```

Instead of using a new List<> every time, we have a kind of 'List Pool', to avoid having to call 'new' every time, and the garbage collector doesn't have to clean it up. In theory, should this be faster or would it lose all of its optimization value because of the call to Clear() every time?

Comment: *"what is better for performance?"* - that depends entirely on how you use it. Your approach may reduce GC pressure in some circumstances, but definitely requires more careful usage (e.g.: remembering to return objects to the pool and not using it afterwards)

Comment: Although if your `List` holds reference types then you will still end up with GC pressure from the objects that you put into the list, so the gains will be miniscule. Such optimizations tend to make more sense with lists of value types

Comment: @UnholySheep What you're saying is: Unless this is a list of string, int, struct, etc.. it's not really worth the trouble to do it this way?

Comment: @NickLokarno: `string` a reference type.

Comment: Why do you use `Stack` and `lock` instead of `ConcurrentStack` without `lock`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentstack-1?view=net-7.0

Comment: I give you Eric Lippert's blog article: ["Which is faster?"](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).

Comment: Good question! Because the programmer that wrote this didn't know it existed! Neither did I...

Comment: @NickLokarno: It's been a few months. You got two answers. We're either of them of use to you? If do, the polite thing would be to accept one if them. Accepting an answer serves two purposes: a) it rewards the answerer, but mote importantly, it provides more information to the next person who has a question like yours and finds this page

Comment: OK, sorry about that, I read your answer back when you posted and I liked it, but I thought I'd wait for more answers/votes to come in before I accepted one, and then I just forgot about the thread. I went ahead and accepted yours just now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, the answer is:

**It Depends**

You don't show the type or the size of `SomeStuff`.  Nor do you say whether `previousAttributes` grows from its initial size during the execution of `FunctionThatGetsCalledAlot`.

If `SomeStuff` (just the collection, not its contents (unless they are value type instances)) is over 85 kbytes, then some of this discussion will have to change - objects over 85k are stored in the Large Object Heap (LOH) and follow different rules.

It's important to realize that the .NET Garbage Collector (GC) is a generational GC.  It has three generations, Gen0 (for objects that were created since the last collection), Gen1 (for objects that have survived exactly one collection) and Gen2 (for older objects).  Gen0 collections are very cheap.  So, your simple implementation *should* not put a lot of stress on the GC - each list will last a short while and will be quickly cleaned up in a Gen0 collection.  One of the larger costs will be the zero-ing out of the new list objects every time you create on (but your `Clear` call probably does a less efficient version of the same work).

One thing you might consider is to create each list so it's the right size to start with:

```
var previousAttributes = new List<SomeClass>(SomeStuff.Length);  //or Count()
```

When you create a list and then you make it bigger than its initial size, it resizes the underlying array by allocating a new array and making the old one eligible for GC.  By getting the size right (or a little bigger than possibly needed), you get rid of the resize.

Where *pools* are handy are when you have large objects (those stored in the LOH).  For a bunch of reasons, LOH objects really stress the garbage collector (they are only every collected in expensive Gen2 collections, their heap management follows very different rules...).  Writing a LOH-capable pool, however, is hard.

All in all, you are very likely better off going with the simple solution.  It's the kind of scenario where the GC does a pretty good job.

Answer (score -1):

Most garbage collectors are optimized for live objects, ignoring garbage (unreachable objects).

An example garbage collector splits the heap into two halves, one active and the other inactive, and copies all objects reachable from `Main` into the inactive half (which then becomes active). If it's 95% garbage, only the 5% real memory takes any work (and allocating merely increments a pointer).

This is wasteful, and garbage collection in real use is more complex and efficient (most active objects also take zero processing each collection), but the point is discarding objects can be thought of as "free" normally.

I'd say in this case, the object initialization (after allocation) would be roughly as expensive as cleaning it up (there will probably be internal objects that are discarded anyway, so you're not avoiding all garbage).

Comment: This answer is unintelligible to me. I'd really like to get a clearer explanation here.

Comment: @Enigmativity Could you let me know at which point I lost you?

Comment: Every single paragraph doesn't make sense to me. Honestly I would be repeating every word. I have read this post multiple times from top to bottom and I really don't understand what any of it is saying.

Comment: The overall gist is that for most garbage collectors, including what C# uses, it doesn't matter how much memory has been discarded (garbage), they only process memory actually in use. I gave a simple example of a garbage collector that shows this, but it's not one that's actually used because it's too simple to be efficient. What it comes down to, related to your question, is that all the effort of saving objects for reuse is probably more than creating new objects. I won't say "always" because situations are unpredictable, so you have to benchmark.